# set default value in dropdown search

Tags: angular

In angular 2 I try to use select2 and semantic-ui dropdown to use dropdown search. It's ok when it doesn't have default value. but when I set default value in page edit data, the data won't show default value. It will show value only if I use "setTimeout()". Anyway I can show default value without setTimeout ?

html (select2 version)

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="input-contactperson" (change)="setContactPerson($event.target.value)">
   <option value="" disabled>please select</option>
   <option *ngFor="let contactperson of objContactPerson" [selected]="contactperson.contactPersonId == contactPerson" value="{{contactperson.contactPersonId}}">{{contactperson.contactPersonName}}</option>
</select>
```

html (semantic version)

```
<select class="form-control ui fluid search dropdown" id="input-contactperson" (change)="setContactPerson($event.target.value)">
   <option value="" data-value="">please select</option>
   <option *ngFor="let contactperson of objContactPerson" [selected]="contactperson.contactPersonId == contactPerson" value="{{contactperson.contactPersonId}}">{{contactperson.contactPersonName}}</option>
</select>
```

In the html above I use [selected] to match value while contactPerson equal  contactperson.contactPersonId It won't show if I don't use setTimeout()

component

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // $("#input-contactperson").select2("val", contactpersonid); //select 2
    $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown("set selected", contactpersonid); // semantic
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [attr.value] for setting the value of a drop down.

ex: [attr.value] = "contactperson.contactPersonId "

{{contactperson.contactPersonName}}

**With null safe opeerator**

{{contactperson?.contactPersonName}}

Also, see if you are getting any exception in console. That could be the case, because you might trying to access the data which was not available the time of rendering the Template UI. 
Like above use the null safe operator "?". This will defer the null/undefined values and when value is available template will show the data.

As you have mentioned data is showing up after a timeout only. Try null safe operator. It should work, you dont need to put a timeout.

Comment: I try using [attr.value] instead of value and also "?" but it's not show default value. I can see different when I add setTimeout and don't add. while I add setTimeout I see the div class="active" in selected value and the default value will show in dropdown but when I don't setTimeout, class "active" is not show in dropdown. look like some kind of rendering UI. anyway [attr.value] is better than value thank. Please tell me if you have another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="select-state" #playerState (change)="0" [(ngModel)]="variable"
        value="{{variable}}"
        [disabled]="isPlayerInfoDisabled" [ngClass]="{'highlight':contactInfoError.has('INVALIDSTATE') && isHighlight == true}">
    <option *ngFor="let s of states; let i = index" [attr.value]="s">{{statesValue[i]}}</option>
</select>
```

Just take the reference of this example as i did for me.
It will definitely work, unless you are doing something else.
in class define this variable as variable: number = 0